# DotNetNuke URL Rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I have a page that I have called menu and the url for the page is mysite.com/menu.

I would like the modules on my menu page to load content according to this url...mysite.com/menu/starters where the 'starters' is the content filter.

So, I have added this to my siteurls.config file...

```
<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*/menu/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/menu</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

...and sure enough when I run this code in a module on the menu page...

```
Dim url As String = Request.RawUrl
If url.Contains("menu/pig-skin") Then
    txtField.Text = "pig-skin has been selected"
Else
    txtField.Text = "No extra url parts."
End If
```

...the condition is met and 'pig-skin has been selected' shows.

So all works fine. Except, when I take the  back out of the siteurls.config file, clear the cash then restart the application, everything runs exactly the same. I would of expected it to throw a Page cannot be found error. Why does it still work?

I'm not even sure if I am doing this correctly. If my code is not even close, how do I achieve this?

Thanks for your time with this.

Answer (score 0):

You really should look at the URL Provider module for modules, assuming you're working with DNN 7.1+ (I recommend 7.2.1 at least, if not 7.2.2)

Otherwise DNN is just loading the page it knows about and the rest of the URL gets ignored essentially.

EDIT: The best reading material for this right now is likely: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/blog/cid/154604/introducing-dnn-extension-url-providers

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am working with DNN 7.2.1. Can you point me to the correct link where I can find the URL Module for Modules. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, if DNN is just loading the page it knows about and the rest of the URL gets ignored, then all I would have to do is grab the rest of the URL, split on the forward slashes and use them as my filter criteria before I GetItems() in my module. Is this a viable way of doing things or should it not be used this way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I added a new URL to a blog post about the providers.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I don't see the URL?

Comment: Yes thank you. I read all that but have not progressed further which was the reason for this post. I asked again at this link...http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/cid/429175